# git merge branch back to specific commit

Tags: git, git-merge

```
        master (branch)
lesson-1 --------------- lesson-2 --------------- lesson-3 ------------ lesson-4
                           /       \
                          /         \
                 lesson-2-mod (branch)
                        /             \
                       /               \
                       - Changes to lesson2
```

I have created a tutorial resource that has commits and tags for `lesson-1`, `lesson-2` etc.
This way users can view and try the code at each step of development by rewinding `HEAD` if they want to.

NOW, I later see a few editions to make to lesson 2 (maybe some time afterward).  The logical visualization of this is to branch off of commit lesson-2, make changes, and merge back into lesson-2.

How would I do this? To date I only have experience merging into a branch which merges to the tip.  I have not branched off of a previous commit, or merging back to a specific point.

Answer (score 0):

This has often happened to me, and what I do is not to make a merge branch but simply to modify the commit/lesson in question (here, your lesson 2). To do so, simply do an *interactive rebase* back to lesson 1:

```
git rebase -i <lesson1>
```

You will be shown, in your editor, a to-do list:

```
pick <lesson4>
pick <lesson3>
pick <lesson2>
```

In the last line (for lesson 2), change "pick" to "edit", save, and close the editor. The rebase will start and pause, waiting for your changes in lesson 2. Revise lesson 2 as desired. Then

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

At this point it is very likely that you will get merge conflicts. Don't be afraid! Simply resolve them as they arise by editing the problematic file(s) directly. When resolved, again say

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

If we pause again with more merge conflicts, do all that again. Eventually you will wind all the way back to where you were, and lesson 2 will have been modified as desired.

Comment: Thank you, and obviously back up first :)

Comment: No need. :) Git _is_ the backup. If you get yourself in a fix. the entire rebase is completely undoable!

Comment: right, so IIRC you'd call `git rebase --abort`

Comment: Even if the rebase completes, you can undo it.